# Custom Metrics stop saving in App Insight after one hour

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights, azure-appservice

I am using Azure services in my application (AppService, AppInsight)

Also, I've implemented my project int **.net Core6**

I am using `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` library (version `2.22.0`)

My Application Insight configuration in appsetting.json is like this

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
     "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=a91c943b-5268-42e1-80c3-dc03c5e9bf0c;IngestionEndpoint=https://easteurope.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://easteurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
 }
```

I've registered the Application insight service like this:

```
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

and my code is

```
private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

public SaveMetricsUseCase(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
{
    this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
}

...

private void SaveMetrics() {

   telemetryClient.GetMetric("ProjectName.PromptTokens", "CategoryId", "Model", "UserId")
      .TrackValue(input.Prompt, input.CategoryId, input.ModelName, input.UserId);

   telemetryClient.GetMetric("ProjectName.CompletionTokens", "CategoryId", "Model", "UserId")
      .TrackValue(input.Completion, input.CategoryId, input.ModelName, input.UserId);
}
```

Whenever I deploy my changes on AppService, the custom metrics are saved properly but after **one hour** the metrics stop storing and I can not see any metrics in the App Insight portal anymore (other logs and exceptions saved in AppInsight without problem, only metrics do not store anymore)

**Have you any idea what the problem might be?**